# Do i need to update AUTH_USER_MODEL in my settings.py?

Tags: python, django

I am creating my own users, `Restaurant` and `Customer`. I have extended the `AbstractUser` class and then created a `OneToOneField` field for each user. I am wondering if I need to add the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my `settings.py`. And also wondering what that does exactly...

What I was planning on doing was adding to my settings.py: 
 `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.Customer','myapp.Restaurant'`

Do I have the right idea here?

My models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    is_restaurant = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_customer = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Restaurant(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.restaurant_name


class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.get_full_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest create single user table instead of three different tables and add type as restaurant, customer, admin etc. And add only one table into settings file. this won't lead any further issues authentication etc. Having single user table is always robust. In your case having three tables seems not good to maintain.

========== UPDATE ===========

Create model for user named as CustomUser (or name which you feel better) and extends to User Model of Django using AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin. like 
`class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser):` have all fields which user table has already. and add your desired table to bifurcate type of restaurant and 
customer have type field with choices option.

For further help you can check section https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: how would i then add attributes specific to each user? I would want the restaurant user to have a `restaurant name` and the customer to have a `customer name`.. make another model with a OnetoOneField, and that is what I am doing

Comment: If you found answer useful then you can as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

No. AUTH_USER_MODEL isn't expecting a tuple, so this won't work.

In any case, Restaurant and Customer are not your user model; your subclassed User is. That's what you should be putting in that setting.